# Java how to return a split array in a function?

Tags: java, function, split

I am learning Java, and as a simple exercise, I am trying to make custom array serialize and de-serialize functions. However, I am having some problems returning a split array. I am expecting the function to return 4 array elements... bob,roger,tim and the last one empty because it splits by "|", but it returns all the characters separate, like:

```
b
o
b
|
r
...
```

I am sure that there is something small that I have overlooked...
Here is my code:

```
public class test{

    public static String SPLIT_CHAR = "|";

    // public functions::
    public static String SERIALIZE(String[] arr){ 
        String RES="";
        for (String item : arr){
            RES +=item+SPLIT_CHAR;
        }
        return RES;
    }

    public static String[] DE_SERIALIZE(String str){
        return str.split(SPLIT_CHAR);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        String[] TestArr = {"bob","roger","tim"};
        System.out.println(SERIALIZE(TestArr));
        String[] DES_TEST = DE_SERIALIZE(SERIALIZE(TestArr));
        for (String Item : DES_TEST){
            System.out.println(Item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` character is interpreted differently by the regular expression engine that `split` uses, basically "empty string or empty string".  Because you have a constant instead of a literal being passed to `split`, I would run it through [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) before passing to `split`, so that it's interpreted literally.

> This method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>
> Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given no special meaning.

```
public static String SPLIT_CHAR = "|";
public static String SPLIT_REGEX = Pattern.quote(SPLIT_CHAR);
```

And when using it:

```
return str.split(SPLIT_REGEX);
```